# Hello World in FlasCC - Getting FlasCC running for the first time in WIndows

Tags: alchemy, flascc

I am reading the README.html instructions.

It says:

1. Extract the contents of the ZIP file onto your hard drive. This can be extracted to anywhere on your hard drive, but this readme will assume it is located at C:\flascc\
2. Ensure 64-bit Java is installed (http://www.java.com/getjava)
3. Ensure Java is on your PATH (http://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)
4. Download the Flex SDK (some of the tutorials require Flex 4.6 or higher in order to be  compiled.)
5. Download a debugger version of the Flash Player (only needed if you want to use GDB to debug your code)
6. Double click the run.bat file
7. Check that FlasCC is working by compiling the first tutorial:

   1. cd 01_HelloWorld
   2. make FLASCC=/path/to/sdk FLEX=/path/to/flex
   3. Launch the hello.swf file

I am not sure about step 2. Does 64-bit Java run on a 32-bit Windows 7? Does that mean I cannot use FlasCC? Does it also mean I cannot run applications that use FlasCC?

The rest of the steps are a piece of cake.

Comment: Can someone please create a flasCC tag? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer on the official forums:

> I don’t think that you can install 64-bit java on a 32-bit system.
>
> If you use FlasCC  with 32 bit java(recommended java is 64-bit) some example will not work due to the memory required. You can try reducing the memory heap allocation by passing –jvmopt=-Xmx1024m to gcc/g++ commands.

HTH,
Gaurav

Credits to Gaurav Jain